# springboot - How to access private git repository files from manifest.yml or Java_Opts

Tags: git, spring-boot, github, cloud-foundry

I have created a folder structure in git repository, so I can use that in my API.
Currently I am not able to load the API into manifest.yml and use those files.
Kinda new to this, need some assistance.

Folder structure in my Git Repository is as below.

```
resources/config/file1,file2
```

Example for Java_Opts variable I am using in my Pivotal Cloud Foundry environment

```
JAVA_OPTS = 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore= path for KeyStore file in local 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword= XXXX 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= path for truststore file in local 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword= XXXX
```

Manifest.yml file example

```
-env
   JAVA_OPTS : 
      -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore= path for KeyStore file in local 
      -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword= XXXX 
      -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= path for truststore file in local 
      -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword= XXXX
```

So I want the above local path to replace a git repository path to access keystore and truststore files.

```
JAVA_OPTS = 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore= GitPath/resources/config/file1 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword= XXXX 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= GitPath/resources/config/file2 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword= XXXX
```

So in the above example, how do I implement Gitpath under Java_Opts variable is my question.

Comment: Please provide some logs related to the your problem

Comment: @borino I didnot try anything yet, not even sure how to access the git repository from manifest.yml in the first place.

Comment: Do you mean `manifest.yml` as in a Cloud Foundry manifest? If so, please tag your question accordingly and give a more detailed description in your question. If something doesn't work, we need to see all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @g00glen00b , Yeah pivotal could foundry/ general Java_Opts variable implementation should also do.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Your application's `manifest.yml` can be used to, among other things, set environment variables. What you reference in the environment variable is totally up to you, however the JVM will expect certain things in it's configuration. I can tell you that `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore` expects you to point to a file on disk though, not in some remote git repository. The only way you could make it pull from a Git repository would be to `git clone` the repo to your local disk first. Then the JVM could load that file from the local filesystem and be happy.

Comment: If you're trying to mesh this together with Spring Cloud Config Server, that's unlikely to work either.  Spring Cloud Config Server is typically used to load application configuration, like data used to configure your Spring beans & application settings.  It's not going to work for a low level JVM configuration like `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` because to get to the point where it could load these values from the remote Spring Cloud Config Server, the JVM would already have to have initialized these values.

Comment: If you need to customize the default key/truststores, you might want to look at the Java buildpack's Container Security Provider which extends some of the JVM's behavior in this area:  https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-container_security_provider.md.  In particular, it makes it easy for Cloud Foundry operators to add additional certificates, like a company CA Cert, which will be trusted across all the apps on the platform.

Comment: @DanielMikusa - +1, Thanks for the above information. I will see if I can get it working by using above solution to put in local.